# Time limit method in objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nstimer, afhttprequestoperation

I have a networking method that request data from a server and then displaying it on the table view. But the problem is when the server is not responding or download takes too long I want to be able to just reload table view with data that is already acquired. I tried using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method but this method will perform selector even if download is finished. I tried creating a bool value to determine if download is already finished when selector is called but this will create **overlap** if download is already finished and then user did another networking action which the selector is not being called yet creating a false action because of this overlap. I want a method that does a time limit but can be canceled if the download already finished. what is the best way of implementing this? or is there a best way to do what I want?

Comment: Show your code, please. The answer depends entirely on the details of _how_ you are doing this data request.

Comment: Regarding *overlap* issue, you can create and share NSMutableArray for each job and insert any value (e.g. `@""`) into it on "job finished" or whatever event you want. NSMutableArray is thread-safe by default, iirc (you should check that to be sure).

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is **not** thread safe.

Comment: I did not remember correctly then :)

Comment: I need all the data because it is used to calculate cell height. kinda like twitter feeds need to be downloaded to calculate label height in cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to cancel your `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` call when the download finishes. For example, when the download finishes, you can call

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:]
```

Here, `target` is the object you called `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` on, `selector` is the selector you passed, `object` is the object you passed (or `nil`).

---

Alternatively, if you only have one performSelector that would be running at a time, there is a simpler method you can use:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:yourObject];
```

`yourObject` will probably be `self` in this case.

Comment: WOW thanks, this is the answer i've been looking for.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're looking for `NSTimer`.  You can start a deadline timer when your network activity begins, and invalidate the timer if the work finishes before the timer fires.

Comment: imagine this, an nstimer is initiated -> download begins and then finished but  the timer has not yet reached its limit -> another download begins ->while the download is happening the previous nstimer just reached its limit ->  reloading table while all the data is not yet finished downloaded even though it is just happened 1 second before.